# Is it better to use SVG or JPG/PNG images for page performance?

Tags: html, css, svg, jpeg

I was wondering if I should switch my JPG and PNG images to SVG, because I believe that using SVG images, my page will load faster, am I sure about that? Is it better to use images in SVG format?
And is there a possibility to convert JPG/PNG to SVG?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are different tools for different jobs.

SVG is for vector images.  Rectangles, lines, ellipses, and all the things you can compose together from primitive objects.  Vector images can scale to most any size and still look decent, because they're not made of pixels.  They're a set of instructions for what to draw on the screen.

PNG is for raster images.  A grid of pixels that represent the image.  These cannot be scaled without loss of quality, as naturally all you can do is make the pixels bigger, or resample the image which gives it various levels of fuzziness in quality.  PNG is great for when you need an alpha channel, need lossless quality of image, or have a lot of solid colors side-by-side, such as the case with computer screenshots.

JPEG is for photos, also raster images.  It's lossy and designed to take advantage of how human vision works to reduce file sizes for images of the real world.

You wouldn't use a JPEG for a vector logo... you'd use SVG.  You wouldn't use a JPEG for a screenshot.  You couldn't use an SVG for a screenshot, as it's a raster image.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're the best

Comment: How about using SVG as Data URL in an IMG ``src``? When does the SVG parser run? on every DOM repaint? Or is it better for performance to convert the generated image to a PNG (using Canvas) and use binary data in the IMG ``src``? (think playing cards generated with SVG, but once in the Browser remain the same size)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Ideally, you don't use data URIs at all.  There is a great deal of overhead, as you're adding 33% to the size of the content for base64 encoding, plus shoving a ton of extra data in the document.  As for your question in general, browsers these days have a ton of nice optimizations, and unless you're doing something unusual, those optimizations are hard to beat.  I have used thousands of SVGs on a document simultaneously with no ill effects.  You should test your specific use case if needed.

Comment: There is no Base64 encoding, SVG goes directly into IMG ``src``. See [CardMeister](https://cardmeister.github.io) With this **Custom Element** I am dynamically creating 52 SVGs, **not** downloading 52 separate SVGs. Using an IMG  guards the SVG (now an IMG) from ever being changed by (global) CSS and from SVG pointer-events issues (a click on the IMG is just a click on the IMG). I am just starting with Drag-Drop interactions. Haven't found any info online yet if the SVG parser kicks in on every DOM repaint. Or is it parsed once when the IMG was created from the (dataURL) SVG?

Answer (score 2):

SVG is a great format for vector graphics. The big advantage is it's sharpness and quality in all sizes / resolution / pixel densities. If you've got some JPG or PNG images that are exported from vector source file (*.AI, *.EPS, *.PDF etc.), I'd consider saving them directly to SVG (e. g. icons or simple shapes graphics). If you don't have a source file, you can try to [vectorize it](https://vectormagic.com/).

However, there is no significant difference in performance. In all these formats you can have both small / optimized images and very large / slowly loading images. If you care about loading times of raster images, you could try image optimizers like [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) or [JPEGmini](https://www.jpegmini.com/).

Answer (score -1):

SVG is better than the JPG/PNG, but if you don't have the image ready with svg, you would use it as a raw format.

Here are why SVG is better than raw format though.

- PNGs can weigh in at large file sizes, usually when catering for HDPI displays. As you know, the larger the file size, the slower it is to render/load.
- SVG is also good for Accessibility and SEO. Google index’s SVGs, which is good news. SVG content whether it is in a standalone file or embedded directly in HTML is indexed.

Comment: This is like saying a fork is better than a spoon.  It really depends on what you need to do.  If there were only one "best" tool, we would just be using that one.  Instead, we have choices of technologies for different problems to solve.

Comment: @Brad actually it's not. have you ever seen the jpg/png is faster than svg?

Comment: if we have everything ready with svg, we will definitely use svg. but unfortunately all images that users have are not svg.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant at all.  Go try to convert a photo to SVG.  What do you plan to do... convert every pixel to a rectangle?  Or, are you going to try to vectorize a photo and make it look all cartoony?

Comment: it's a little hard to convert to the correct image from the jpg, as i told, if we have everything ready by svg, we will use svg.

Comment: we dont have everything by svg, that's why we use the raw format like png/jpg

Comment: Exactly my point.  If you have vector, use SVG.  If you have a raster image, you'll need a raster format like PNG or JPEG.  And, only use JPEG for photos.  The person asking the question is simply asking if one format is better over the other, and of course that's not the case.  They're used for different things.  The context matters, as I outline in my answer.  You would never want to attempt to convert from PNG to SVG unless it was something that belonged in a vector format to begin with, and you lost the original file, and needed a place to start from redoing it.

Comment: what I wrote is SVG is faster and good approach to use if you already have the image as svg.

Comment: What you wrote in your answer is, "Yes, SVG is better than the JPG/PNG", and "There are many online PNG -> SVG converter".  This is the problem.

Comment: i guess the important thing of the question is which is better between svg and png, rather than converting png to svg is better.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I could understand what you meant, it all depends on what I'm using. Thank you for your help!